# Only create plots for data frames that contain data

Tags: r

I have a for-loop going and creating plots for multiple variables in a a list called 'codes'. In some cases, the subsets will not contain anything. When this happens, my code fails because it can't create the plot. Is there a way to only use the plots that contain data?

```
for (x in codes){
    x1 <-subset(data.Age0, CD==x)
    x2 <-subset(data.Age2, CD==x)
    x3 <-subset(data.Age3, CD==x)
    x4 <-subset(data.Age4, CD==x)

    plot1<-ggplot(data=x1, aes(x=x1$PYMT))+geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,80,by=2))+ labs(title="Age Group 0")+labs(x="Payments",y="Frequency")
    plot2<-ggplot(data=x2, aes(x=x2$PYMT))+geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,80,by=2))+ labs(title="Age Group 2")+labs(x="Payments",y="Frequency")
    plot3<-ggplot(data=x3, aes(x=x3$PYMT))+geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,80,by=2))+ labs(title="Age Group 3")+labs(x="Payments",y="Frequency")
    plot4<-ggplot(data=x4, aes(x=x4$PYMT))+geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,80,by=2))+ labs(title="Age Group 4")+labs(x="Payments",y="Frequency")

    grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4)
}
```

Comment: Try `lst1 <- Filter(length, lst)` and then use the `lst1` for the calculations.

Comment: you are arranging four objects, if one doesn't contain data, what do you do with that--a blank plot or skip?